# Display: inline-block + float + resize. Как это работает?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

[Код](https://jsfiddle.net/gegfw516/5/).

```
<style>
.c {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.i {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.i1 {background-color: #aaa;}
.i2 {background-color: #bbb;}
.i3 {background-color: #ccc;}
</style>

<div class="c">
  <div class="i i1"></div>
  <div class="i i2"></div>
  <div class="i i3"></div>
</div>
```

Откуда берется пустое пространство у родителя(с боку), когда при ресайзе окна браузера элемент с флоат прыгает вниз? Ведь по существу, родитель должен плотно прилегать к детям, а не растягиваться на всю ширину, насколько мне известно.

Как сделать так, чтобы он прилегал к детям?

Answer (score 1):

Третий блок "прыгает" вниз при ресайзе из-за того, что на его ширину при данном масштабе окна не хватает места. При этом при "прыжке" родительский блок будет иметь максимальную ширину, т.к. минимально необходимая ширина родительского блока при `display: inline-block` - при которой все блоки умещаются в строчку (без переноса). Если необходимо плотное прилегание, используйте `<br>` для переноса "прыгающих" блоков на следующую строку.

Comment: Спасибо. Интересно.
Как вам такое решение: https://jsfiddle.net/gegfw516/6/

Comment: Тоже подумал об @media но это, к сожалению, не валидно. Вообще в принципе от `<br>` при использовании блочной вёрстки надо избавляться.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

```html
<div>
  <div style="float:left;display:inline-block!important;width:70px;padding:5px;border:1px solid;">Дитё 1</div>
  <div style="float:left;display:inline-block!important;width:70px;padding:5px;border:1px solid;">Дитё 2</div>
  
</div>
```